# Why are eigenvectors of an invertible matrix linearly independent?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Why are eigenvectors of an invertible matrix linearly independent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Who said they had to be? What about

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{array}\right]?$$

EDIT: Michael, below, is correct. In your PDF, the author is not asserting that an invertible matrix has linearly independent eigenvalues. Rather, the argument is that since the eigenvectors of $A$ are the columns of $P$, and $P$ is invertible, it must follow that the eigenvectors of $A$ are linearly indepedent (which is just using the fact that an invertible matrix has linearly independent columns).

Comment: In these lecture notes (http://www.maths.lse.ac.uk/personal/martin/fme3a.pdf), I found the following sentence, that left me confused:
Since P has an inverse, these eigenvectors are linearly independent.

Comment: $P$ is a matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors of the matrix $A$. Since $P$ is invertible, the eigenvectors (of $A$) are linearly independent.